# background http requests on ios for "killed app"

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, background, geolocation

I read a lot about iOS backgrounding but I still have issues understanding the concept for *one specific case*.

When my app is killed with taskmanager (or by iOS because of memory pressure) and a significantLocationChange or GeoFence happens, my whole app is started by iOS and my callback method is called.

First question here is: what state am I in? Even the UI is partly loaded so I'm kind of foreground, but since there is nothing on the display, I consider it being background.

My second and main question is, how can I send http requests AND resend them if the internet connection is down currently?

I have tried to use `[NSThread sleepWithInterval]`, `dispatch` with delay and `NSTimer`. All of them with the same bad result: It works great in foreground, great in NORMAL background (user pressed homebutton) but very bad in the state described above. I'm able to send multiple http requests if they run fast enough but when I need several seconds with sleep, I get killed randomly. When I use a Timer with 2 second delay, I'm able to reach my "resend http request" method 2-3 times bevor all output of the app stops. If I use my planned delay of 30 seconds, I don't even get the timer call once.

So a last question is: Is there a backgroundpermission that I need to register? I already use

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
   <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Or would it help to use NSOperationQueue? Does it have special permissions that I don't have?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the application state by calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]
```

In your case it should be `UIApplicationStateBackground`.

---

If you using a `NSURLSession` for your network requests, you can set it up with a background session configuration. When your app is in the background, this will allow networks requests to be handled by the system even when your app isn't running.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'm able to see, that I am really in the background (enum 2), thats good to know at least.

Comment: But for your other point, I'm already using NSURLSession, the problem is, I still need a Timer or similar that will call the the method that does NSURLSession. And it seems that the app is dead before the timer triggers.

Comment: There is no way around that, your app only gets a small amount of time to run in the background. Since I dont know why your trying to add a timer, I'd say try and solve the problem without using a timer.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion? I'm open to any solution and I think it should be a quite simple task, all I want to achieve is to retry HTTP requests after a small delay when they failed (most likely because of connection issues). But they are send in the background on geo-updates, even when the app is killed.

Comment: Use a background url session, it waits for a good internet connection before running the request.